# Laravel query - andWhere

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with my Query

When I run it like this bellow I get ALL Groups and Items (table items) for all organisations. Its meaning to get only Groups from the `org_id` and where they are visible.

```
return $this->model->with( [ 'items' => function($query){$query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orWhere('invisible', '=', null)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');} ] )->where("org_id",$org_id)->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orWhere('invisible', '=', null)->orderBy('description', 'asc')->get();
```

if I run it like this ( dropping the `invisible` query for the groups) it works fine.

```
return $this->model->with( [ 'items' => function($query){$query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orWhere('invisible', '=', null)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');} ] )->where("hos_id",$hos_id)->orderBy('description', 'asc')->get();
```

How doe I do a

```
WHERE orf_id= org_id
AND ( invisible = false OR invisible = NULL )
```

Comment: it should be `whereNull('invisible')` which would produce `WHERE invisible IS NULL`. Checking equality with NULL doesn't always do what one would expect. This is not the actual problem you have but worth pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by

```
$query->where(function($query){
    $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orWhereNull('invisible');
})
```

So finally you code will be like

```
return $this->model->with( [ 'items' => function($query){
    $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orWhereNull('invisible')->orderBy('description', 'ASC');
}])
->where("org_id",$org_id)
->where(function($query){
    $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orWhereNull('invisible');
})
->orderBy('description', 'asc')->get();
```